# In my while loop values are not being stored

Tags: perl

In the following example, `@DAYS` is the days of the month and the entries in `@DAYS_SINCE_RAIN` correspond to the entries in `@DAYS`, e.g. `$DAYS_SINCE_RAIN[4]` is the number of days since it last rained on `$DAYS[4]`.

In `@DAYS_SINCE_RAIN`, a day that has rain would have a value of 0. I want the last instance at which 0 appears.

```
#iii. Find the last day of rain in April 2013.
print "#iii. Find the last day of rain in April 2013.\n";
$i=0;
@getday=();

while(@DAYS_SINCE_RAIN[$i]=~ m/0/){
    push @getday, @DAY[$i];
    $i++; 
    if($i=$#DAYS_SINCE_RAIN){
        last;
    }
};

print "@DAYS_SINCE_RAIN";
print "\n day of last rain: @getday[$i] ";
```

It appears that no values are being stored :(

Comment: Where are `@DAYS_SINCE_RAIN` and `@DAY` coming from?

Comment: copy/paste output of `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@DAY, \@DAYS_SINCE_RAIN;`

Comment: Better use `$` to access array elements than `@`. Also `m/0/` would match `10`, `20`, etc.

Comment: the data is coming from another text file, which i have stored in an array. this is me accessing those arrays

Comment: @CathleenTurner-SantillanMera it would be helpful to include mentioned data in your question

Comment: Okay, I posted how I got the data. it is from the .txt file. FOr the file itself see: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61787383/April13.dat

Comment: You can't afford to turn off (comment out) `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  Expert Perl programmers use them all the time to make sure they aren't making silly mistakes.  Beginning programmers should do the same.

Comment: Yeah, guilty as charged. I won't do it again, rookie mistake. But when I uncomment it I get a bunch of errors! It's probably because of the section where I take the data from the .dat and put it into an array :p it gets the job but the implementation is not correct. WHat should I do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the assignment operator rather than comparison here:

```
if($i=$#DAYS_SINCE_RAIN){
```

Change the `=` to `==`.

In addition to this, the loop:

```
while(@DAYS_SINCE_RAIN[$i]=~ m/0/){
```

Will exit on the first day without rain. You could take a slightly different approach, start at the end and work back:

```
my $i = $#DAYS_SINCE_RAIN;

while ($i >= 0) {
    last if $DAYS_SINCE_RAIN[$i] == 0;
    $i--;
}

print "\n day of last rain: $DAYS[$i] ";
```

Comment: Thanks @RobEarl, this is awesome. So to make sure I understand, I am saying, 1) let I be the total number of elements I will look at 2) while i is greater than 0 (or equal) look at days at rain data starting at the last data element. subtract i if you dont find it. the first one you find, exit the loop, the print the corresponding day element.

Comment: @CathleenTurner-SantillanMera yep, that's it.

Comment: thanks! Would you mind suggesting improvements for when I am writing a .txt file? it is not working and I do not know why, I don't know how to debug no perl (can do on matlab) @RobEarl

Comment: @CathleenTurner-SantillanMera there are some good suggestions in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030643/my-code-to-write-a-txt-file-from-my-data-isnt-working-what-am-i-doing-wro