# My code to write a .txt file from my @data isn't working :(. What am I doing wrong? I am using a while loop

Tags: perl, while-loop

iv. Write the following output to a new file with columns separated by tabs ("\t"):
DATE, MONTH, MAX TEMP, MIN TEMP, MAX HUMID, MIN HUMID

```
#a declare vars
@riteline=();
my $headers;
my $riteAline;
print 'iv. Write the following output to a new file with columns separated by tabs ("\t"):';
print "\n DATE, MONTH, MAX TEMP, MIN TEMP, MAX HUMID, MIN HUMID";
$headers= ("DATE,MONTH,MAX TEMP,MIN TEMP,MAX HUMID,MIN HUMID");
$headers=~ tr/,/\t/;

#first you can turn the arrays into string
 open (my $fh,'>', 'DATAEXPORT.txt') | die "Could not open file :( fix bugs";
 $i=0;
 $ii=0;
 #the loop to match data by index and seperate with tab
 while (<FILE>) {
 chomp;
 if($i=0){
 $fh=$headers;
 print "$fh\n";
 $i=1;
 }else{
 @riteline=(@DAY[$ii],"\t",@MONTH[$ii],"\t",@MAX_TEMPERATURE[$ii],"\t",@MIN_TEMPERATURE[$ii],"\t",@MAX_HUMIDITY[$ii],"\t",@MIN_HUMIDITY[$ii]);
 $fh=join('\t',@riteline);
 print "$fh\n";
 $ii++
 }
 };
 close (FILE);
 print "HW 2 complete";

 My error msg just comes up :(
```

EDIT1: I made the following changes by a few people's gracious suggestions, but I have no output.... I am not sure why, am I doing something fundamentally wrong? The arrays DO exist btw

```
# iv. Write the following output to a new file with columns separated by tabs ("\t"):
# DATE, MONTH, MAX TEMP, MIN TEMP, MAX HUMID, MIN HUMID

# a delacre
@riteline = ();
my $headers;
print 'iv. Write the following output to a new file with columns separated by tabs ("\t"):';
print "\n DATE, MONTH, MAX TEMP, MIN TEMP, MAX HUMID, MIN HUMID";
$headers = ('DATE,MONTH,MAX TEMP,MIN TEMP,MAX HUMID,MIN HUMID');
$headers =~ tr/,/\t/;

# first you can turn the arrays into string
open(my $fh, '>', 'DATAEXPORT.txt') || die "Could not open file :( fix bugs";
$i  = 0;
$ii = 0;

# the loop to match data by index and seperate with tab
while (<FILE>) {
  chomp;
  if ($i == 0) {
    print $fh $headers, "\n";
    $i = 1;
  }
  else {
    @riteline = (
      $DAY[$ii],             "\t", $MONTH[$ii],           "\t",
      $MAX_TEMPERATURE[$ii], "\t", $MIN_TEMPERATURE[$ii], "\t",
      $MAX_HUMIDITY[$ii],    "\t", $MIN_HUMIDITY[$ii]
    );
    print $fh join("\t", @riteline), "\n";
    print $fh @riteline, "\n";
    $ii++;
  }
}
close(FILE);
print "HW 2 complete";
```

Comment: Why do you store filehandle in `$fh` and overwrite it with a string? Where was `FILE` opened?

Comment: indentation is a programmers most powerful tool.

Comment: Never say things like this `My error msg just comes up :(` without saying what the error is. Also, never say "its not working" without specifying *how* its not working.

Comment: because I don't know what I am doing? :) this is how I would approach the problem in matlab...is there a more perl-y way to do this? @Jokester

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your errors come from :

```
$fh=$headers;
print "$fh\n";
```

and

```
$fh=join('\t',@riteline);
print "$fh\n";
```

You' d write:

```
print $fh $headers,"\n";
```

and

```
print $fh join("\t",@riteline),"\n";
```

for the last one I think you want:

```
print $fh @riteline,"\n";
```

Also, don't use `@DAY[$ii]` but `$DAY[$ii]`

Comment: when you say TYPE: print $fh join("\t",@riteline),"\n"; and TYPE:print $fh @riteline,"\n";       ........ wouldn't that be printing the output twice? If not, why?

Comment: Good news! I made the changes and it opened a new .txt! Sadly it is blank :(

Comment: @CathleenTurner-SantillanMera: Just use one or the other of the last two instructions, the one that fits your requirement.

Comment: @CathleenTurner-SantillanMera: I don't know what you are reading in the while loop, insert some debug to see what happened.

Answer (score 3):

> My error msg just comes up :(

It would because you say:

```
open (my $fh,'>', 'DATAEXPORT.txt') | die "Could not open file :( fix bugs";
```

Say:

```
open (my $fh,'>', 'DATAEXPORT.txt') || die "Could not open file :( fix bugs";
```

or

```
open (my $fh,'>', 'DATAEXPORT.txt') or die "Could not open file :( fix bugs";
```

Of course, the other issues have been pointed out by [M42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/m42) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19030730/2235132).

Comment: This is because using the `|` operator will always evaluate both sides whereas `||` will "short circuit" and only evaluate the right hand side if the left hand side is false.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you are reading through whatever you have opened on filehandle `FILE` to populate the various arrays `@DAY`, `@MONTH` etc. Then you are trying to read it *AGAIN* to output the data in the arrays, but it is already at end of file so your `while` loop never executes.

In addition to applying

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to the beginning of your code, and declaring all your variables with `my` as appropriate, I suggest this instead

```
my @headers = ('DATE', 'MONTH', 'MAX TEMP', 'MIN TEMP', 'MAX HUMID', 'MIN HUMID');

open my $fh, '>', 'DATAEXPORT.txt' or die "Could not open file: $!";

my @columns = \(@DAY, @MONTH, @MAX_TEMPERATURE, @MIN_TEMPERATURE, @MAX_HUMIDITY, @MIN_HUMIDITY);

print join("\t", @headers), "\n";

for my $i (0 .. $#DAY) {
  my @line = map $_->[$i], @columns;
  print $fh join("\t", @line), "\n";
}
close $fh;

print "HW 2 complete";
```

Comment: thank you @Borodin, it worked. if you don't mind me asking, can you tell me what you are doing here as if I am 5 years old? I'd like to understand how this code is implimented. Also, why are you doing a \( for @column?

Comment: Well you really need to understand references and `map` first. I set `@columns` to references to your data arrays, so `$columns[0]` is a reference to `@DAY`, `$columns[1]` is a reference to `@MONTH`, etc. The `for` loop executes with `$i` set to 0 to the last index of `@DAY` (assuming all the arrays are the same length). The `map` statement takes the i'th element from each array referred to by `@columns` and puts them in `@line`, so `@line` is set to `($DAY[$i], $MONTH[$i], ....)`. Then the `print` statement just joins them with a tab separator and prints out the line. Hope that helps?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by *"Also, why are you doing a ( for @column?"*